# What should I do about a low quality answer that's helpful?

Tags: support, answers

I got [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1167801/513819) on one of my questions that helped me a lot. However, the answer is incomplete and would fit better as a comment. Although it was very helpful to figure out where the problem was coming from, it doesn't actually provide a solution. The reason why it wasn't posted as a comment is probably because the user who posted it doesn't have enough reputation to do that.

I've already posted a comment on the answer to tell the person who posted it that it was useful but needs more information. If it wasn't useful, I would have flagged it as not an answer, but now I don't want to do that since it would risk getting deleted and deleting this answer would delete valuable information.

What should I do about this? Flag it with a custom flag to ask a moderator to turn it into a comment? Leave it alone? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helped you find a solution, then put the found solution into a proper answer and then accept your own answer. If the answer is low quality, flag it as such.

Alternatively, improve the existing answer with the knowledge it helped you find.

Comment: I didn't find a solution. The answer helped me in the sense that it said that it's an app causing the problem and that it might be connected to a setting in the app (which I had no idea about when asking the question), but I can't find that setting and the answer doesn't say anything about which setting it is.

Comment: Then it should simply be a comment. Flag it as low-quality. The moderator will usually know whether it needs to be converted to a comment or not.

Comment: I flagged the answer as you suggested and it got deleted without being converted to a comment, so I edited my question to include the helpful information from the answer.

Comment: Sounds even better :)